# How to create three "like" image buttons in one row ( one aside another) in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to create three "like" image buttons in one row ( one aside another) in jquery mobile ?

I have tried like this

```
<body>
    <a class="ui-icon-google" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="google" data-theme="a"/>
    <a class="ui-icon-facebook" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="facebook" data-theme="a"/a>
    <a class="ui-icon-twitter" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="twitte" data-theme="a"/a>
</body>
```

with css like

```
.ui-icon-google{
    background-image: url("google.png") !important;
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
}

.ui-icon-facebook{
    background-image: url("facebook.png") !important;
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
}

.ui-icon-twitter{
    background-image: url("twitter.png") !important;
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 192px;
    height: 192px;
}
```

but it one above another ( what is wrong, I am trying to put icons for openid like on stackoverflow )

Answer (score 0):

You need images  first then you can link the images to your location.

Comment: I have images in same folder like css and it shows but buttons are one below another(three rows one column) and I want to be asside (one row three columns)

Answer (score 0):

make it [a grid](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html) :

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
     <a class="ui-block-a ui-icon-google" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="google" data-theme="a"/>
     <a class="ui-block-b ui-icon-facebook" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="facebook" data-theme="a"/a>
     <a class="ui-block-c ui-icon-twitter" href="#" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="twitte" data-theme="a"/a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a inline button group:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Up</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Down</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Style it as you wish. Take a look at [this](http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/) link, here you will find many more examples of jQM GUI elements. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YJfzP/

Answer (score 0):

Make the images inline or imline-block elements. Add the following style to .ui-icon-google, .ui-icon-facebook and .ui-icon-twitter:

```
display: inline;
```

Or,

```
display: inline-block;
```